# Style for wrapped text with spreadsheetml

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, spreadsheetml

I generate my spreadsheet with xslt and want a cell with wrapped text (or better: a text with a line break in it).

So my xslt generates the following XML for the sheetdata:

```
<sheetData>
  <row r="1">
    <c r="A1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
        <t>
          a simple string
          line break jeeeehaaa
        </t>
      </is>
    </c>
  </row>
</sheetData>
```

After I'm finished building my Workbook, I open it in Excel; and there's no line break, just a simple one-line string in A1.

has anyone a solution to this? Doesn't have to be in xml or xslt (but would be nice). I could also do some things in c#

Comment: This doesn't look like SpreadsheetML.  This looks like Office Open XML.  See [Microsoft Office XML Formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) for a description of the differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In excel, all style related information is stored in style.xml file.
So, the wrapping information should be stored in style.xml and the style Id should be referred in `<c r="A1" t="inlineStr">` as one more attribute 's' (which means style). Let me show what do I mean by this..

I do have an excel with some text and the cell is wrapped indeed.

If I see its sheet.xml data it would have `s="1"` attribute-value item in `<c>` tag.

So, if I open style.xml and see the cell style info I'll get `<cellXfs>` tag and a `<xf>` child tag where I get a `<alignment>` tag with wrapText attribute with value as "1" ("true" indeed).

I'm unable to post images since I'm new to SO. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, it worked... here's the xml for the style
__<xf>
  <alignment wrapText="1" />
</xf>__